Solana Transaction Prioritization Problem: Higher Priority Fees & Lower CU Usage Still Result in Slower/No Confirmations
I have a problem with Solana Transaction Prioritization that seems to contradict all network prioritization metrics. (FYI: I am using Quicknode RPC)
Let's look at two transactions:
Our transaction (https://solscan.io/tx/4Pwiy5vHB5HHA57WMxxoqUfK3Ng5pScMHv8L2c5UUN5eS3i8T84y58RphPfBmmDU396K7nqSEkYAcHHhwcLWuNC3):
Compute Unit Price: 8.38 lamports per compute unit
Priority Fee: 0.001 SOL ($0.1738)
Compute Units Allocated: 119,283
Compute Units Actually Used: 96,226
Result: Required multiple attempts, several minutes to confirm
Phantom's transaction (https://solscan.io/tx/3JqLWxLAn5LTqcuvCDDW87MEeEZfgUCmxMsAuacA6cB6wecHMooM5coZ8wnEkNNK1DW1yxiVvC4uFD2S8PbjyAYb):
Compute Unit Price: 1.3 lamports per compute unit
Priority Fee: 0.0004 SOL ($0.06954)
Compute Units Allocated: 307,893
Compute Units Actually Used: 243,618
Result: Instant success, confirmed in seconds
Our transaction should be prioritized by ALL metrics:
Higher compute unit price (6.4x higher: 8.38 vs 1.3)
Higher priority fee (2.5x higher: 0.001 vs 0.0004 SOL)
Lower compute unit usage (96k vs 243k used)
I'm aware of the common advice about compute unit allocation affecting validator preferences. However, in this case, that explanation doesn't apply because:
Our transaction uses LESS compute units (96k vs 243k)
We have LOWER CU allocation (119k vs 307k)
Yet we have HIGHER fees and priority
According to standard validator behavior:
Validators prefer transactions with lower CU usage (ours uses less)
Validators prioritize higher fees (ours has higher fees)
Block space is limited to 1.4M CUs (our tx uses less block space)
By every single metric that affects transaction prioritization, our transaction should be preferred by validators and included faster than Phantom's. Yet we consistently see the opposite.
Has anyone encountered similar issues or can explain what might be causing this behavior? All the standard explanations about CU allocation and priority fees don't seem to explain what we're seeing here.
Here is my jupiter swap configuration:
const swapResponse = await axios.post("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap", {
    quoteResponse: quoteResponse.data,
    userPublicKey: user,
    wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
    computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: 1200000,  // This results in ~8.38 lamports/CU
    dynamicComputeUnitLimit: true
});

Here is my tx logic:
const sendAndConfirmTx = async (sendConnection, signedTx) => {
  const rawTransaction = bs58.decode(signedTx);
  const signature = await sendConnection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
    skipPreflight: true,
    maxRetries: 2,
  });

  let retries = 0;
  while (true) {
    try {
      await sendConnection.confirmTransaction(signature);
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      if (retries > 5) {
        throw e;
      }
      retries += 1;
    }
  }

  return signature;
};

I already set the fees super high and hoped that it would help, but it did not do anything.
Perhaps it is a quicknode problem, that they do not forward our txs properly?

Because of MEV, validators may include transactions that they have private deals with. There is nothing in Solana that would enforce a validator to pick your transaction even if its fees are higher. This is called censorship resistance and effectively validators are censoring your transction.
Kyle Samani, from Multicoin Capital, is a large investor in Solana ecosystem and is a proponent of MEV and this kind of behaviour. It is a crooked game and there is interest to keep it this way.
